# How do I set a jQuery selector in coffeescript using a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Im writing a Rails app, and I have multiple forms on the same page that all have different ids. in coffee script, I'm trying to set the identifier to access the text area in each. heres a quick example of what the html looks like in the browser.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="link" data-plan="1">Click here</a>
<form id="new_item_plan_1">
  <textarea id="plan_1_item_field"></textarea>
</form>
```

Setting the plan id and trying to access the text area

```
plan_id = 0
$(".link").click ->
  plan_id = $(this).data("plan")
$("#plan_"+plan_id+"_item_field").keypress ->
  ...Some code...
```

So I have the `plan_id` variable initialized first, then set it to the `.link`s data-plan value. But my key press event doesn't work on the textarea and I dont get an error in the console.

When I make a test link and `console.log` it...

```
plan_id = 0
$(".link").click ->
  plan_id = $(this).data("plan")
$("#test).click ->
  console.log(plan_id)
```

it prints the correct `plan_id` value in the console just fine, so I have to be doing something wrong in the textarea identifier. What am I going wrong? Thanks.

Link to jsfiddle, notice how the keypress event doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/cfscr/175/

Comment: you essentially want to dynamically add a keypress listener to your text areas, yes?

Comment: Yea, i have multiple forms added by rails that I have set their ids to their respective objects. I need to be able to dynamically access them in my coffee script. I've reproduced my example here https://jsfiddle.net/cfscr/175/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening in your code is that the keypress binding is applied on page load, so its only applied once while plan id is still 0. it doesnt get re-applied when plan_id is updated.

I should note this seems like an odd thing to be doing, but you need to put the binding inside of the click event. that is, you want

```
$("#plan_"+plan_id+"_item_field").keypress ->
  ...Some code...
```

to be applied each time the click event is fired.
to do so, it must be indented properly

```
plan_id = 0
$(".link").one 'click', ->
  plan_id = $(this).data("plan")
  $("#plan_"+plan_id+"_item_field").keypress ->
    ...Some code...
```

this will make is so that when the user clicks the button any number of times, it will apply the binding to that keypress.
Is this what youre trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense as to why it won't set it correctly. What I'm trying to accomplish is when the `.link` is clicked, it sets the `plan_id` so I can select the correct textarea. My textareas are id'd as `#plan_1_item_field`, '`#plan_2_item_field`, ... because there are multiple forms on the page. I need to be able to select them to execute some code that happens on keypress. I'll putting the keypress inside the click event, is there any advantage of doing it this way instead of @jpriebe s way?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" class="link" data-plan="1">Click here</a>
<form id="new_item_plan_1">
  <textarea id="plan_1_item_field" class='item-field' data-plan='1'></textarea>
</form>

plan_id = 0
$(".link").click ->
  plan_id = $(this).data("plan")
$(".item-field").keypress ->
  if $(this).data('plan') == plan_id {
     ...Some code...
```

you could use a regex instead of another `data` tag in the text area, i'm just lazy ;)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a class instead of a dynamic id, and it works for the example i wrote, but i just wrote the example for brevity sake. I have a bunch of different dynamic selectors I need to be set